# Redirect query strings to another url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect  my urls that have query strings

example -

**domain/user.php?username=tom&age=25&location=japan**

I want to redirect it to a an another url

**domain2/profile.php?u=tom&age=25&location=japan&page=current**

Tried it

```
RewriteRule user.php http://domain2.com/profile.php?u=tom&age=25&location=japan&page=current [R=301]
```

is not working

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use %{QUERY_STRING} server variable to match against the query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^username=([^&]+)&age=([^&]+)&location=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^user\.php$ http://domain2.com/profile.php?u=%1&age=%2&location=%3&page=current [NE,NC,R,L]
```